# Show original links in Outlook 365

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

In the Outlook component of Microsoft Office 365, when reading an email that contains a link, the link is shown as `https://<server>.outlook.com/owa/redir.aspx?C=<alphanumeric key>.&URL=<URL-encoded URL>`.

How can I have the original link instead? I want at least the following:

- When I click on the link, the linked site opens directly, without making a request to `outlook.com`.
- When I copy the link to the clipboard, the link is copied as it was in the email.
- When I hover the mouse over the link, the real target appears at the bottom of the window.

I'm open to a solution that involves a userscript, but I'd prefer something that works in all main browsers including IE 8.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a [skip-owa-redir userscript](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andersk/andersk-userscripts/master/skip-owa-redir.user.js) that replaces each indirect `redir.aspx` link with a direct link to the target URL, using `rel="noreferrer"` to address the [privacy concern](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/exchange-2003-owa-and-url-redirection/ba-p/610152) that motivated `redir.aspx` in the first place.

Comment: I think the `privacy concern` link is dead. Is it possible to update it, or cite it in a more permanent way?

Comment: Also, how would one install and/or use your userscript?

Comment: @jvriesem Thanks, updated the link. Userscripts are loaded with a userscript manager such as [ViolentMonkey](https://violentmonkey.github.io/).